# PHPUnit assertTag fails when content contains unicode

Tags: phpunit

The following assertion fails to correctly assert the statement when $content contains unicode characters.

```
$matcher = array('tag' => 'div', 'content' => $value);
$this->assertTag($matcher, $content);
```

Currently, I'm using assertRegExp to get around it.

```
$this->assertRegExp('/<div>' . $value . '<\/div>/', $content);
```

But I would appreciate if anyone can shed some light on how to make assertTag work. Thanks!

P.S. I should also point out that the same code works in a Linux environment but not in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) or alternatively its inverse `htmlentities()` with the `ENT_QUOTES` flag:

```php
$matcher = array('tag' => 'div', 'content' => html_entity_decode($value, ENT_QUOTES));
$this->assertTag($matcher, $content);
```

or

```php
$matcher = array('tag' => 'div', 'content' => $value, ENT_QUOTES));
$this->assertTag($matcher, htmlentities($content, ENT_QUOTES);
```